# AngularJS $animate.addClass(element, className, [options]) don´t fire the css added and return an callback error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to change CSS values ​​in my animation as is detailed in the official documentation of AngularJS via addClasst without external JQuery plugings. The css transition run, but not the css passed in the options parameter. Also i receive a callback error:

Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function 
(anonymous function)

What is wrong?

Controller:

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module("VixMain", ['ngAnimate', 'vixParticles']);

app.controller("VixCtrl", ["$http", "$scope", "$document", "$animate", function($http, $scope, $document, $animate){

    var beggar = this;
    this.section = 0;

    beggar.backgrounds = [];

    this.bgContent = angular.element($document[0].querySelector(".bgContent"));

    this.changeSection = function(id){

        this.section = id;
        this.bgContent.removeClass("bgResize");
        $animate.addClass(this.bgContent, "bgResize", {from:{left:"10px"}, to:{left:"20px"}});
    }

    $http.get("/data/sections.json").success(function(data){

        beggar.sections = data;

        for(sec in beggar.sections){

            beggar.sections[sec].menu = data[sec].title.split(/(\.{3}|[^\w\s\.,\'])/g);
        }
    });


    }]);
```

CSS:

```
.bgResize.bgResize-add.bgResize-add-active{

opacity: 0;
}

.bgResize.bgResize-add{

-webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
transition: all ease-in 1s;

display:block!important;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you post you code to jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Your problem here is with the 'this' reference inside of the chaneSection function, you either need to transfer the this assignment to a variable : var that = this outside of the changeSection function and than use that.bgContent. however you can post jsfiddle so i can check that for sure.

Comment: I try to put the variable as you say but i receive the same result, perhaps the cause is that queryselector returns an array and must be a single element. Now its very late here and i did several changes in my code, sorry, but tomorrow at first time i post the fiddle, thanks for response ;)

Comment: I post this jsfiddle with the changes you say here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/damnvix/f1xgo2b9/). The element from queryselector is correct, only take the first item of the array